# Cannot get div innerhtml to work correctly with highcharts chart object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, highcharts

So I am trying to work towards having this checkbox inside this to be clicked and it will switch what chart is displaying. That is not what I am worried about. After using ajax it correctly hits the function and returns an object from the function and I cannot use .innerhtml to get it to fill the div.

Here is my  View code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block card-header height-px-55">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        Top 5 Drivers (Based on NAV) <span class="pull-right">
                            <input class="form-check-input chartSwitch" type="checkbox"
                                   data-charttoggle-enabled="true" data-charttoggle-opt-1="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Portfolio_Performance_TopDriversChart), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(),  new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })"
                                   data-charttoggle-opt-2="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Portfolio_Performance_TopDriversChart_Percent), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(),  new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })" id="top5Switch" checked data-on-text="@Model.Currency.CurrencySymbol" data-off-text="%" />
                        </span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block chartToggle" id="top5">
               
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the javascript I am trying to get working.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').find('input[data-charttoggle-enabled="true"]').each(function () {
            var opt1 = $(this).attr('data-charttoggle-opt-1');
            var opt2 = $(this).attr('data-charttoggle-opt-2');
            var divtochange = $(this).parent().parent().parent().next();
            var id = $(divtochange).attr('class');
            alert(id);

            $.ajax({
                url: opt1,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,                
                success: function (data) {                  
                    $(divtochange).innerhtml(data);
                },
                error: Functions.Elements.ajaxError
            })
        });      

    });
</script>
```

and here is what gets returned as data in the ajax success

```
public ActionResult ChartBuilderToPartialView(Charts.ChartBuilderResult result)
        {
            if (result.ChartCompleted)
            {
                return PartialView(SharedPageURLs.ChartView.GetDescriptionAttribute(), result);
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView(SharedPageURLs.NoData.GetDescriptionAttribute(), new Models.NoDataErrorViewModel { Message = "No Data Found" });
            }
        }
```

This is what gets returned to the partial view.

and this next part is what is on the view that gets returned to the javascript as Data.

```
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Rendering;
@model Client_Portal.Charts.ChartBuilderResult

@Html.Raw(Model.Renderer.RenderHtml(true))

@{
    var chartID = $"createChart{Model.Chart.ID}()";
}
<script>

    window[@{WriteLiteral(chartID); }];

</script>
```

and just a bit more here is the Model that is on that last partial view.

```
public class ChartBuilderResult
    {
        public bool ChartCompleted { get; set; }
        public ChartError Error { get; set; }
        public Highcharts Chart { get; set; }

        public HighchartsRenderer Renderer { get; set; }

        public class ChartError
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

So really I think the issue is what is getting returned in the partial view window[@{WriteLiteral(chartID);};
Any idea how i can get what is returned there to be able to be inserted using .innerhtml?

Comment: First have you tried to console log inside `success` to see if you get data?. second try `console.log(divtochange)` to see if you have the expected element

Comment: I have the alert in the success to show that data is an [object,object]
also no but i used alerts to make sure it was the correct div and DivTochange Is correct.

Comment: Hi @Snake3ite, As far as I understand, received `data` is a JSON with chart options, am I correct? If so, instead of using `innerHTML`, you need to update or recreate the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Rendering
@model Client_Portal.Charts.ChartBuilderResult

<div id="chartContainer_@Model.Chart.ID" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

@{
    var chartID = $"createChart{Model.Chart.ID}()";
}

<script>
    $(function() {
        window[@(chartID)];
    });

    function @(chartID) {
        var chartOptions = @Html.Raw(Model.Chart.ToJsonString());
        Highcharts.chart('chartContainer_@Model.Chart.ID', chartOptions);
    }
</script>
```

in the view the chart returns.

and your jquery/javascript could be soemthing like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').find('input[data-charttoggle-enabled="true"]').each(function () {
    var opt1 = $(this).attr('data-charttoggle-opt-1');
    var divtochange = $(this).closest('.card-block').next('.card-block.chartToggle');

    $.ajax({
      url: opt1,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      context: this,                
      success: function (data) {
        // Clear the existing content in the div
        $(divtochange).empty();

        // Render the chart using Highcharts library
        if (data.ChartCompleted) {
          var chartID = 'createChart' + data.Chart.ID;
          window[chartID]();
        } else {
          // Handle the case when there is no chart data
          var noDataMessage = 'No Data Found';
          var errorPartialView = '@Html.Partial(SharedPageURLs.NoData.GetDescriptionAttribute(), new Models.NoDataErrorViewModel { Message = "' + noDataMessage + '" })';
          $(divtochange).html(errorPartialView);
        }
      },
      error: Functions.Elements.ajaxError
    });
  });      
});
```